# Where's a good place to ask questions that are considered to broad in scope for SU?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I need to ask questions that are broad in scope, which leads to them being rejected here.

Where's a good place which is more welcoming of such questions than SU?

Comment: Can you provide an example? Ironically, this question is currently very broad too.

Answer (score 4):

"**too broad**", doesn't mean off-topic, so there could not be by-default suggestion for migration.

When a question is closed as too-broad, that generally means one, or combination of these reasons:

- multiple questions are asked in the same post

  - splitting it to multiple posts (maybe with link to each other) may solve the problem
- there is no appropriate research behind the question (e.g. asking for a definition of TCP)

  - searching the internet might solve your problem. Even if it can't solve your problem, you get some basic idea and can improve your post buy asking a more specific question
- expecting the community to do someone's job.

  - Most frequently people ask for macros to be written (please give me a macro which ...). It's simply off-topic here, if somebody can't write macro, then need to hire a professional to do it.
- The topic is not suitable to be discussed in a Q&A site like Superuser.

  - I see your question [Is this a complete local backup solution definition?](https://superuser.com/questions/1414845/is-this-a-complete-local-backup-solution-definition) has been recently closed as off-topic. It mainly falls into this category. It is too broad because you ask multiple questions, touch a very broad topic, it also has some subjectivity and software recommendation in it.
  - Maybe you can discuss this better in a forum, or staying in Superuser, look for a chat room.
- not enough details are included to understand situation / be able to find the right solution.